# prevent text selection on pdf in \ruby context

Tags: xetex, copy-paste, xecjk

I was wondering if there is an "easy" way to prevent selection on furigana produced by `\ruby` command so it's easier to select>copy>paste on translator or other place.

```tex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\setCJKmainfont{Microsoft JhengHei}

\begin{document}
  \ruby{赤}{あか}いです,そして\ruby{新}{あたら}しいです
\end{document}
```

for instance, if i copy the following piece (in the result pdf)

[image]

And then i go and paste it (on the browser, for example) I get : そして`あたら`新しいです. The `あたら` part is the one i want to avoid to be selected.

I was hopping for some latex magic like

```
\ruby{赤}{あか}いです,そして\ruby{新}{\UNSELECTABLE{あたら}}しいです
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it's because I am not knowledgeable enough but I do not understand the question at all. Maybe you can provide a more complete example that's compilable and better explain the context and the problem.

Comment: Probably it's due to my english being terrible. I tried to improve my question a bit @Dr.ManuelKuehner

Comment: Make a small but complete example, one starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document} which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: For those go are not familiar with Japanese: It has three alphabets. Two of them have symbols for syllables without inherent meaning and the third (kanji) are symbols with meaning. Because there are a lot of kanjis, sometimes small syllable symbols (furigana) are placed above them to help readers who are not familiar with that symbol, for example in school texts or when using obscure ones. These are not strictly part of the text, so when you copy text out of a PDF, you might want to skip them (especially if they loose their designation as furigana otherwise).

Comment: @EikeSchulte That's an awesome explanation of why i want to achieve that! It's exactly my motivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. But not every pdf viewer will honor the setting.
`\NewDocumentCopy` requires a quite current LaTeX, in older LaTeX you can use the `letltxmacro` package and the `\LetLtxMacro` command instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xecjk}
\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\NewCommandCopy\ORIruby\ruby
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ruby}[2]{%
\ORIruby{#1}{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=}#2\EndAccSupp{}}}
  
\begin{document}

\ruby{赤}{あか}いです,そして\ruby{新}{あたら}しいです

\end{document}
```